# How do I show a minimal left ideal of a finite dimensional simple algebra exists? What can you say about its endomorphism ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

How do I approach this ?

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $R$ a $k$-algebra which is also a finite dimensional vector space over $k$. Suppose $R$ has no two-sided ideals other than $0$ and $R$. Show that $R$ has a simple left ideal $I$. What can you say about the ring $\mathrm{End}_R(I)$? Justify your answer.   **6 Marks**

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihn2R.jpg)

Also What does simple left ideal mean here ?

Comment: A left ideal that's a simple left $R$-module?

Comment: I think you are right. Although the phrasing is not the best here. It could also mean a left ideal which, as a ring, is simple.

Comment: Hi: I've taken the liberty to transcribe your question. This makes your question more searchable. We wouldn't want people thinking you were trying to obscure the fact it is obviously off a test, and that you were trying to cover your tracks, now would we?  I've also removed the commutative-algebra tag since it seems inappropriate. $R$ and $End_R(I)$ will generally be noncommutative.

Comment: I've also altered the title to be not useless. You ought to do the same while writing questions in the future.

Comment: Thank You @rschwieb

Answer (score 0):

A simple left ideal is one which, considered as a left $R$ module, is simple (i.e. there are exactly two submodules: the zero submodule and the submodule itself.)

Every left ideal is patently a subspace of the finite dimensional space $R$. From all dimensions of nonzero left ideals there is necessarily one of minimal dimensionality, and that is clearly a simple left ideal.

The fact that the endomorphism ring of a simple module is a division ring is known as Schur's Lemma, and it is so well-known nobody asks for proofs of it here.  Nevertheless, you can [find one here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma#Formulation_in_the_language_of_modules). You can say even more about it, also on the same wiki page.